# What is special about the admin in chef?

Tags: chef

I've read over the chef docs for a while now and I can't seem to find anything that says what an admin does in chef.  I can [do all sorts of things with making people admins](https://docs.chef.io/server_users.html), but there's no indication of what this does for me.  Is there a clear answer somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Chef admin](https://docs.chef.io/server_orgs.html#admins) can create, modify and delete other users and clients. Basically an admin can manage access to Chef.